# failed to start (Result: start-limit) [debian - datadog agent]

Tags: debian, systemd, failed-installation, datadog

**What did I do?**

via command line on my debian 8.x host.

```
DD_API_KEY=[...] bash -c "$(curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/master/cmd/agent/install_script.sh)"
```

**Expected behaviour:**

```
● datadog-agent.service - "Datadog Agent"
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/datadog-agent.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-04-24 10:42:36 CEST; 10h ago
```

**Actual behaviour:**

```
● datadog-agent.service - "Datadog Agent"
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/datadog-agent.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2018-04-24 21:13:40 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 22628 ExecStart=/opt/datadog-agent/bin/agent/agent start -p /opt/datadog-agent/run/agent.pid (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 22628 (code=exited, status=255)

Apr 24 21:13:40 worker-1 systemd[1]: Unit datadog-agent.service entered failed state.
Apr 24 21:13:40 worker-1 systemd[1]: datadog-agent.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 24 21:13:40 worker-1 systemd[1]: Stopping "Datadog Agent"...
Apr 24 21:13:40 worker-1 systemd[1]: Starting "Datadog Agent"...
Apr 24 21:13:40 worker-1 systemd[1]: datadog-agent.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Apr 24 21:13:40 worker-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start "Datadog Agent".
Apr 24 21:13:40 worker-1 systemd[1]: Unit datadog-agent.service entered failed state.
```

**Problem:**

I can not start the service due to Result state: start-limit.
I waited about 9 hours. My idea was the service state will recover from to many restart attempts. It did not. Any ideas?

Comment: As a Data Dog customer, you should ask *them* why their software isn't working as expected.

Comment: @MarkStosberg I do not believe it is an issue related to data dog. I do think one should be able to manually force restart the service without failing due to start-limit.